# Создание и удаление динамических массивов

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Как правильно создать динамический массив на 100 элементов? Как удалить потом значение каждого его элемента? Как удалить весь динамический массив?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вы не создавали каждый элемент по отдельности, то и удалять нужно все вместе. В случае с массивами это `delete[] имя_массива;` - парная функция к `new[]`

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, в C++ правильным путём является использование `std::vector`.

Создание массива просто:

```
std::vector v(100);
```

Удалять его не надо: vector самоудалится, когда выйдет из окружающего блока видимости. Чтобы контролировать время жизни массива, либо заведите его в нужном блоке, либо положите в какой-нибудь класс, либо положите в динамическую память — вариантов множество, описаны в книге по C++, которую вы, надеюсь, сейчас читаете.